# Setting the transaction isolation level for a H2 via a DataSource

Tags: java, postgresql, transactions, h2

I'm trying different isolation levels for my application because of an issue with concurrent updates. I set the isolation level through a DataSource from which I get the database connection

```
BasicDataSource ds = new BasicDataSource();
ds.setDefaultTransactionIsolation(
  Connection.TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ)
/* more config ... */
ds.getConnection()
```

With a postgres 9.3 database, concurrent updates on rows triggers an error, which is expected and according to the postgres documentation on [Standard SQL Transaction Isolation Levels](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html#MVCC-ISOLEVEL-TABLE)
`ERROR: could not serialize access due to read/write dependencies among transactions`
This error vanishes as expected when setting the isolation level to `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`

Trying to reproduce this behavior with an H2 in memory database, the isolation levels don't seem to change the outcome of my unittest. Even with deactivating isolation altogether with setting the database url with [LOCK_MODE=0](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation) and/or `Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED` I get errors on concurrent updates `org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Concurrent update in table "MyTable": another transaction has updated or deleted the same row`

My question would be: How do I configure the H2 connection to use a specific isolation level, none of my changes to the lock mode or the connection help me get rid of the JdbcSQLException.

Comment: https://www.h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_lock_mode
here is about h2 LOCK_MODE

Comment: This seems to be the command: [SET SESSION CHARACTERISTICS AS TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL value](http://h2database.com/html/commands.html#set_session_characteristics). Allowed for `value` are `READ UNCOMMITTED`, `READ COMMITTED`  `REPEATABLE READ`, `SERIALIZABLE` (partially supported), the ANSI-defined [isolation levels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isolation_%28database_systems%29#Isolation_levels). `SNAPSHOT` may also work. See also [Transaction Isolation](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#transaction_isolation) Now, let's see some JUnit tests.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer if you had asked in 2016 I may have created an example project :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

H2 is not supposed to be running in multi-threaded environment. You may use it for development purposes, etc. but on a threaded, heavy-load environment you should use an instance of a full-featured DBMS.

Comment: hmm, "you can't use H2 for that" is not really the answer I hoped for :)

Comment: Good enough for IPC and storing data, isn't it? If it works, it works. If you want ACID, [it's there](http://h2database.com/html/advanced.html#acid)